# System.Globalization.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear() returns odd results

Tags: c#, .net, calendar, week-number

I'm in the middle of calculating week numbers for dates, but the `System.Globalization.Calendar` is returning odd results for (amongst other years) December 31st of year 2007 and 2012.

```
Calendar calendar = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar;
var date = new DateTime(2007, 12, 29);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    int w = calendar.GetWeekOfYear(date, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"), w);
    date = date.AddDays(1);
}
```

**Results**

```
29.12.2007      52
30.12.2007      52
31.12.2007      53 <--
01.01.2008       1
02.01.2008       1

29.12.2012      52
30.12.2012      52
31.12.2012      53 <--
01.01.2013       1
02.01.2013       1
```

As far as I understand, there shouldn't be a week 53 in year 2007 and 2012, but the days should be included in week 1. Is there a way to change this behaviour in the `Calendar`?

Comment: "The days are supposed to be included in week 1": according to which rule? According to the rules I know, the last days of the year are never part of the first week of the next year...

Comment: According to ISO 8601. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: BTW, why are you using that weird date format? I think I have never seen dates written as `2007.12.29`.

Comment: Has your answer been resolved..??

Comment: @svick it sorts chronologically when `yyyy-MM-dd`, but edited for readability

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [documentation for the CalendarWeekRule enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendarweekrule.aspx) specifically states that it "does not map directly to ISO 8601", and links to [ISO 8601 Week of Year format in Microsoft .Net](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=160851), a blog entry that describes the differences.

Comment: This explains everything. Thanks

Comment: I don't even want to look at the workaround. My simple question is: Why? Who benefits from it? Why *slightly* change so that you have to pick two dates out of ten to see a difference? A little frustrating...

Comment: @Piddu most likely because the team that implemented it was not aware of the standard, and after it was released, they didn't want to make a breaking change to the logic.  This contrasts with the .NET implementation of Unicode, which doesn't comply with the standard because it predates the standard.  (I'm not certain that ISO 8601 didn't change after the .NET logic was implemented, but the ISO standardized the calculation of week numbers in 1976, so it seems unlikely.  It's also worth noting that the ISO standard reckons the beginning of the week on Monday, which conflicts with US practice.)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the values of [`CalendarWeekRule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendarweekrule.aspx). You are using `FirstFourDayWeek`, and so you are getting the values you describe. If you want every week to have exactly 7 days, you should use `FirstFullWeek`.

In your case, that would mean that 31. 12. 2007 will be week 53, but so will 2. 1. 2008.

Comment: That solution doesn't comply with the ISO 8601, since *the first week with the majority (four or more) of its days in the starting year [is week 1]*

Answer (score 1):

Starting with .net core 3 there is a new ISOWeek that actually does calculate WeekOfYear correctly

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.isoweek.getweekofyear

Answer (score 0):

There don't have to be 52 weeks for the week identifiers to be unique, you just don't necessarily have 7 days in a particular week.

If this is a problem for you then add code to handle the edge case.

Comment: There is always 7 days in a week.