# Why is this date not in the week of the next year? (C# calendar)

Tags: c#, date, calendar

I want to calculate the week number of a given date.

```
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime("31.12.2001");

DateTimeFormatInfo dfi = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
System.Globalization.Calendar cal = dfi.Calendar;

int weekOfYear = cal.GetWeekOfYear(date, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek,  
   dfi.FirstDayOfWeek);
```

In my DateTimeFormatInfo, the first day of week is a monday. I want to use the four days rule, means a week belongs to a year in which the majority of its days lie.
The 31st of December 2001 is a monday and should then be in week 1 of 2002. However, weekOfYear is returned as 53.

Does someone know what´s wrong?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/662379/

Comment: Not a direct duplicate, but there is some good info in the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [the documentation for `CalendarWeekRule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendarweekrule.aspx) for the exact rules. In short, December 31 will never be week 1, it will be always something like 52/53. The values on the enumeration influence what week will the first days of January have.

Comment: See also [System.Globalization.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear() returns odd results](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8808878/41071).

Comment: This makes no sense. A week should always have 7 days. What weird stuff is MS doing?